# How to fix the width of the button with my own button class

Tags: android, button, height, width, drawable

I have created a buttons class because I need the buttons to have a specific height and width depending on the screen size;
so here's my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyButtons extends Button {

       public MyButtons(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

            setHeight(height/8);
            setWidth(width/6);

            Log.d("btheight",height*1/8+"");    

         }


}
```

in the xml filde I have

```
<pachagename.MyButtons
        android:id="@+id/access"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
       android:background="@drawable/aw"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
        />
```

how can I fix the height and the width so it doesn't change depending on the drawable size I mean I need it to be as added in the mybuttons class...
but now it's still changing depending on the drawable size because it's wrap_content so what should I use instead to tell it to take the width and height specified by the Mybuttins class?

My layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/app_cover"

     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/L1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/L2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >    
      <packagename.MyButtons
        android:id="@+id/access_awkat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
       android:background="@drawable/awkat"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
        />  

     <packagename.MyButtons
        android:id="@+id/access_mofadala"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
       android:background="@drawable/mofadala"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
        />     

     <packagename.MyButtons
        android:id="@+id/access_introduction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
       android:background="@drawable/mokadima"
        />
       </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/L2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"

         >

    <packagename.MyButtons
        android:id="@+id/about_program"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bernamej"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         />

    <packagename.MyButtons
        android:id="@+id/user_settings"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
       android:background="@drawable/edadat"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />
    <packagename.MyButtons
        android:id="@+id/access_remembrances"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:background="@drawable/azkar"

        />



    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this in a custom View? And why do you want the button to be 1/8th of the height, and 1/6th of the width of the screen for ALL devices?

Comment: here you no need to Customize button for setting width and height. you can do that via LayoutParams of a Button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height and width of the bottom LinearLayout by putting this code in the onCreate() of your activity:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

View view = findViewById(R.id.L2);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
params.height = height / 8;
params.width  = width  / 6;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Make sure to change the layout_height of all the buttons in that layout to "fill_parent" and then they should all be 1/8 the height of the screen.

Comment: I have a certain image and I want the buttons to be at the buttom of that image and the image contains text but at the buttom it has a 1/8 free space so here I want to display my buttons.. that's what I'm doing..

Comment: You most likely can do all of that with a RelativeLayout, and without a custom MyButtons class and without using LayoutParams. Perhaps you should post your layout.xml if you're using one

Comment: ok I placed my relative layout it contains my buttons, please can you tell me how can I make the buttons fit in the 1/8 of my screen

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer and hopefully that explains it.

Comment: I edited the code to show you can set the width just like the height. Another way to accomplish that is to set the width of each button to "0dp" then set the weight to "1.0". Also set the LinearLayout's width to "fill_parent". Then layout inflater will make each button the same width until they fill the screen.

Comment: yeah thanks I deleted my comment because I knew how to do it :) I did it with the weight..